# Wagtail: how to set calculated fields (@property) title in admin

Tags: wagtail, modeladmin

I use ModelAdmin module for my models in Wagtail.
I have @property fields in models, where I return some annotated data and display it Index and Inspect Views in Admin. But Wagtail set title of such fields as field name in model. In regular field I use verbose_name to set nice title, how can I change titles for property field?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `ReadOnlyPanel` as it is not possible with Wagtail.

`mypanel.py`

```
from django.forms.utils import pretty_name
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import EditHandler

class ReadOnlyPanel(EditHandler):
    def __init__(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        self.attr = attr
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clone(self):
        return self.__class__(
            attr=self.attr,
            heading=self.heading,
            classname=self.classname,
            help_text=self.help_text,
        )

    def render(self):
        value = getattr(self.instance, self.attr)
        if callable(value):
            value = value()
        return format_html('<div style="padding-top: 1.2em;">{}</div>', value)

    def render_as_object(self):
        return format_html(
            '<fieldset><legend>{}</legend>'
            '<ul class="fields"><li><div class="field">{}</div></li></ul>'
            '</fieldset>',
            self.heading, self.render())

    def render_as_field(self):
        return format_html(
            '<div class="field">'
            '<label>{}{}</label>'
            '<div class="field-content">{}</div>'
            '</div>',
            self.heading, _(':'), self.render())
```

And to use it just import and use in your model:

```
from .mypanel import ReadOnlyPanel
class YourPage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ReadOnlyPanel('myproperty', heading='Parent')
    ]
```

Original source: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2893